# Problem in dependency drop down using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-8

**I'm trying to get the Document types in a drop down based on the department selected in another drop down. We are getting successful data from Department drop down (see console output in the first row) but second drop down is not working. Getting the following Error in second row**

[image]

**front view**

```
<div class="col-xl-2">
                <select  class="department form-select form-control"  name="updept" id="selectdeparment" aria-label="Default select example">
                    <option selected="false" value="" >Department</option>
                    @foreach ($deptdatas as $item)
                        <option value="{{$item->deptid}}">{{$item->deptname}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2">
                <select  class="type form-select form-control" name="updoc" id="selectdocumenttype" aria-label="Default select example">
                    <option selected="false" value="0">Document Type</option>
                    {{--@foreach ($docdatas as $item)--}}
                        {{--<option value="{{$item->docid}}">{{$item->docname}}</option>--}}
                    {{--@endforeach--}}
                </select>
            </div>
```

**controller**

```
$data=Doctype::select('docname')
            ->where('docid',$request->deptid)
            ->take(100)->get();
        return response()->json($data);
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).on('change','.department',function(){
                console.log("hmm its change");

                var item_deptid=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('findProductName')!!}',
                data:{'id':item_deptid},
                success:function(data){
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.length);
 }
                });
            });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to expand that line in the Console to get the specific error message

Comment: @ADyson Question edited with expanded Console line

Comment: `$request->deptid` There is no `deptid` in your request

Comment: @brombeer what should i write here. Can you suggest?

Comment: Take a closer look at your URL and your AJAX function: which parameter/data are you sending?

Comment: You're sending a parameter called `id` but it looks like the php code expects one called `deptid`